# Running an existing Macro on a new Excel File automatically when opened

Tags: excel, vba

(Excel 2010 question)

I have a reporting application that exports To excel. I have a Macro created that does some functionality. I need to run this macro whenever I open this new Excel Workbook after I export it.

Since it's a brand new worksbook, the excel does not have the macro that I have created embedded into it. So need to know if this is possible and how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to open the workbook and process it with a PowerShell script. A VB script (.VBS) could do the same thing but I'd probably use [PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell).

Comment: You can create an add-in which hooks to the Application `Workbook_Open` event: see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Comment: You can create the report with the macro already embedded. How do you create your reports now? What is the language/library that you use to create the reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can open both the workbook that contains the macro and then the NEW workbook.

Then hit F11 for the Developer's Console.  Usually it opens with the Project Explorer open on the left.  If it isn't you can open it in the View menu, or by hitting Ctrl+R.

You need to copy the module that contains the macro into the modules of the New Workbook.  Either insert a module from the Insert menu, or right click on the Modules > Insert > Module, then copy and paste the code, or you can just INSERT the module.

Let's assume your original Macro is named "Macro1".  Make sure it isn't private.

I made one for example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox("Welcome to the Workbook!")
End Sub
```

In the Project Explorer, select the New workbook, and there should be an object titled "ThisWorkbook".  Right click on that and select "View Code".

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Macro1
End Sub
```

Save it, exit, open it back up and see your macro execute.

Comment: I am a developer, so I have an understanding yes.  The idea was to make sure that the end user of the exported files go through less number of steps each time. So do let me know if there is an easier solution .

Comment: I understand now.  What language is your Reporting Application written in that you are using to export to Excel, and is it something you developed?

Comment: It's a silverlight application - using Telerik Reporting to create the report. So the Export functionality comes out of the box from telerik